# How do I move a file (or folder) from one folder to another in TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I would like to move a file or folder from one place to another within the same repository without having to use Repo Browser to do it, and without creating two independent add/delete operations.  Using Repo Browser works fine except that your code will be hanging in a broken state until you get any supporting changes checked in afterwards (like the .csproj file for example).

Update: People have suggested "move" from the command line. Is there a TortoiseSVN equivalent?

Answer (score 453, accepted):

To move a file or set of files using `Tortoise SVN`, right-click-and-drag the target files to their destination and release the right mouse button. The popup menu will have a `SVN move versioned files here` option.

**Note that the destination folder must have already been added to the repository for the `SVN move versioned files here` option to appear.**

Comment: I needed to do the same and this worked perfectly. Never knew about this option. Big thanks!

Comment: Thank you!  Note: Afterwards, it shows in the change log a bunch of DELETED and ADDED files and directories, but the revision history does follow the files around.  :)

Comment: What do I do if I already moved the file but svn still thinks its in another directory?

Comment: You also (certainly in v1.7.6) need to make sure that the directory you are moving the files is already added subversion

Comment: Legendary answer made my day, ty!

Comment: it should be mentioned that you have to use the Windows Explorer to move. Tools like the Total Commander did not support this feature.

Comment: While I prefer answers that involve the portable svn command line to answers that use an OS-specific tool like Tortoise SVN (even though I see the OP specifically asked for a Tortoise SVN answer, I still think the best answer would include both options), the comment that "the destination folder must have already been added to the repository" helped me resolve the error I was getting from the Linux command-line client, so you get the upvote.

Comment: Of course there must be a subsequent commit, which sends the change to the repo; you can edit the files before committing (e.g. to fix paths...) But any commit must include both the deleted dir and the added dir (or neither); the simplest thing is to commit at a common containing directory. But if you have unrelated mods in the common tree which you do not want to commit at the same time, that may not be an option; a command line allows you to name both of the affected dirs directly and sidestep this issue.

Comment: @ThomasFranz Using Total Commander is a very specific case, most people here don't.

Answer (score 59):

`svn move` — Move a file or directory.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re18.html

Answer (score 21):

In Windows Explorer, with the right-mouse button, click and drag the file from where it is to where you want it. Upon releasing the right-mouse button, you will see a context menu with options such as "SVN Move versioned file here".

http://tortoisesvn.net/most-forgotten-feature

Answer (score 6):

Under TortoiseSVN, see the following page: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-copy.html

Answer (score 5):

If you want to move files around **and** keep the csproj files up to date, the easiest way is to use a Visual Studio plugin like [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.net). 
That will automatically commit both the move action (as an delete + add with history, because that's how Subversion works) and a change in the .csproj

Answer (score 4):

From the command line, you can type `svn mv path1 path2`. This will create an add and a delete operation, but there's not really a way around that - as far as I know - in Subversion.

Answer (score 3):

Subversion does not yet have a first-class rename operations.

There's a 6-year-old bug on the problem: http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=898

It's being considered for 1.6, now that merge tracking (a higher priority) has been added (in 1.5).

Answer (score 1):

Use Tortoise's RENAME command, and type in a relative path ("folder/file.ext").

Answer (score 1):

You have to drag the file using the right mouse button. The moment you release the file to the new destination you will observe the option:

> SVN move versioned files here.

Just select this option and you are done !!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `svn move` command to move file/folder.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier, you'll create the add and delete commands.  You can use svn move on both your working copy or the repository url.  If you use your working copy, the changes won't be committed - you'll need to commit in a separate operation.

If you svn move a URL, you'll need to supply a --message, and the changes will be reflected in the repository immediately.